# What will happen to a running process if I change its systemd service unit?

Tags: centos, systemd

I have a systemd service unit that starts a python server application.

The systemd service unit is already in a running state on the system.

I need to change some directives in the systemd service unit without affecting the running processes that this service spawned. I want to do these changes so that they will be applied when the python server application is restarted, which might be a month from now.

Is this a safe thing to do ?

Also, is it safe to run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

after modifying the service unit. Will this affect the running processes that this service spawned ?

I wasn't able to find information about this in the man pages of systemd. Maybe I missed it, maybe it is safe, I don't know.

**OS:** CentOS 7.6

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen to your running service unless you stop or restart it.